# Passport - TypeError: passport.authenticate is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to implement a `passport` authentication strategy to my application, but keep getting the following error after trying to sign in:

> TypeError: passport.authenticate is not a function at exports.signin

I'm pretty sure that I have missed something but cannot figure out what could that be. Since there aren't anything related to authentication inside the `user` model, I decided not to output it in here.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
|-- project
    |-- .env
    |-- index.html
    |-- package.json
    |-- server.js
    |-- app
    |   |-- config
    |   |   |-- passport.js
    |   |   |-- routes.js
    |   |   |-- test.js
    |   |   |-- passport
    |   |       |-- local.js
    |   |-- controllers
    |   |   |-- users.js
    |   |-- models
    |       |-- user.js
```

Here's my `routes.js` file

```
/* Config / Routes */

'use strict';
const users = require('../controllers/users');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.post('/login', users.signin);
    app.post('/users', users.create);
};
```

Here's my `local.js` for `LocalStrategy`:

```
/* Config / Passport / Local */

'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = mongoose.model('User');

module.exports = new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
        User.findOne({email: email }, function (err, user) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' });

            if(!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });

            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
);
```

Here's my `passport.js` file where the `LocalStrategy` is assigned to the `passport`:

```
/* Config / Passport */

'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const local = require('./passport/local');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(local);
};
```

Here's my `users.js` controller file:

```
/* Controller / Users */

'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const only = require('only');
const passport = require('../config/passport');

/* Creates a new user */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    // create a new user object of request body
    const user = new User(only(req.body, 'firstName lastName email password'));

    // attempting to create a new user
    user.save(function (err, user) {
        if(err) {
            // output validation errors
            return res.json(err);
        }
        // output created user
        return res.json(user);
    });
};

exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);

        if (!user)
            return res.status(401).json({message: info.message});

        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            next(err)
        });

        res.json(req.user);
    })(req, res, next)
};
```

And finally, my `server.js` file:

```
/* Server.js */

'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./app/config/test');
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
if(mongoose.connect(config.db)) {
    console.log("Connected to a database");
}

/* Database Models */
const User = require('./app/models/user');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(passport.initialize());

/* Bootstrap Routes */
require('./app/config/passport')(passport);
require('./app/config/routes')(app);

app.listen(port);
console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);

// log the current API version
console.log('Current API version: ' + process.env.API_VERSION);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your users.js file, change the below line

```
const passport = require('../config/passport');
```

to

```
const passport = require('passport');
```

I was facing the same issue. we have to import library, not the passport.js we have created in the config folder.

Comment: I Was struggling a bit until I've found my mistake thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have already found the solution, but it might help someone else in the future.

In your *users.js*, you are requiring the *config/passport.js*. But it doesn't return a passport object. It just call the *use* method.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it worked with 
`import passport from "passport";`